# Прокрутка блоками css

Tags: css3

Сделал для примера три блока. У всех высота 100vh. Не пойму как сделать так, чтобы если мы прокрутили вниз (тоже самое и вверху), второй блок вылетал на всю высоту, то есть на весь экран, и тд, а не смотрелся половина одного, половина другого блока.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Блоки</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="block1"></div>
        <div class="block2"></div>
        <div class="block3"></div>
    </body>

</html>

html {
    height: 100vh;
}
.block1 {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.block2 {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: chocolate;
}
.block3 {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: firebrick;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если изобретать свои велосипеды, то можно так :)

И да, на чистом `CSS` это сделать нельзя.

```js
// подписываемся на события скрола колесиком
$(window).on('mousewheel', function(e) {
  // тут мы определяем в какую сторону скрольнули и в зависимости от этого будем показывать соответсвующий блок
  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
    scroller.showPrev();
  } else {
    scroller.showNext();
  }
});

var scroller = {};
// показывает следующий блок после текущего
// принцип: хватаем текущий блок,
// берем следующий через .next(), если он существует - скроллим к нему
// предварительно смотрим чтобы мы уже не скроллились
scroller.showNext = function() {
  if (this.isScrolling) {
    return;
  }
  let current = scroller.getDisplayingBlock();
  let next = $(current).next();
  if (next) {
    scroller.scrollToElement(next);
  }
}
// показывает предыдущий блок
// принцип: хватаем текущий блок,
// берем предыдущий через .prev(), если он существует - скроллим к нему
// предварительно смотрим чтобы мы уже не скроллились
scroller.showPrev = function() {
  if (this.isScrolling) {
    return;
  }
  let current = scroller.getDisplayingBlock();
  let prev = $(current).prev();
  if (prev) {
    scroller.scrollToElement(prev);
  }
}
// возвращает текущий блок
// принцип: смотрим текущую позицию скролла
// по коллекции элементов .block ищем первую,
// которая находится на позиции текущего скролла +-10
scroller.getDisplayingBlock = function() {
  let scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
  let item = Array.from($('.block')).find(function(el) {
    return Math.abs(el.offsetTop - scrollPosition) < 10;
  });
  return item;
}
// скроллит к блоку
// сетает флаг isScrolling=true
// с помощью .animate анимирует скролл
// после завершения скролла сетаем обратно isScrolling=false
scroller.scrollToElement = function(el) {
  this.isScrolling = true;
  let thisScroller = this;
  let elTopOffset = el.offset().top;
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: elTopOffset },
    600, function() { thisScroller.isScrolling = false; });
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
  height: 100vh;
}

.block1 {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.block3 {
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block block1"></div>
<div class="block block2"></div>
<div class="block block3"></div>
```

Почитать:

- [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)
- [`.animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: благодарю)) как я понимаю на чистом css это не решить никак?

Comment: @PaulWall да, я уже прочел ваш коммент в ответе ниже и добавил к ответу :) Сейчас докину комментов в код что где делается

Comment: спасибо))) я тут на сайте недавно, скажите за одно плиз, как в сообщение вставлять код, чтобы была кнопка Выполнить код как у вас

Comment: @PaulWall `ctrl+m`, либо иконка листа с `<>`

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ - использовать плагин [fullpage](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

Comment: а на чистом ccs это возможно?

Comment: нет, невозможно.